# trouble looping through div ids with newest jquery build

Tags: javascript, jquery

I upgraded my website to the latest jquery build (2.1.4), and I'm trying to debug the many errors that it is throwing.

However, I keep getting the error "unrecognized expression: [id=]" on the following script:

```html
setTimeout(function() {
$(".cab_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas_user").each(function () {
  var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
  if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
    $(ids[1]).remove();
  }
});
```

and I can't wrap my head around it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is value of `this.id`  when failing?

Comment: You script implies that there are multiple ids on the page: not good.

Answer (score 1):

At first I was going to write a comment advising to put support requests directly on jQuery, but then I saw the code and thought it merits some discussion.

First of all, the `id` attribute is a special attribute in HTML. It is supposed to hold a unique value throughout the whole document (in other words, no two elements can have the same `id`), so I'm finding it strange that code would ever work.

Secondly, I don't see any reason why you would use jQuery to select an element by id when a simple `document.getElementById()` would have done the trick. Let's say you wanted to have a jQuery element. Fine, even in that case, your jQuery selector is far from perfect. A better alternative would be `$('#' + this.id);`. That said, the best alternative would be a simple `$(this)`... no need to worry about the id at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand the new jquery build, but normally you would declare your id within the jquery wrapper with

```
$('#myId')
```

Your code is assigning

```
var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
```

which translates to this

```
ids = $('[id=whateverThisIdIs]');
```

Can you try this instead?

```
var ids = $('#' + this.id); // assuming this.id does not contain '#'.
```

Final

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".cab_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas_user").each(function () {
  var ids = $('#' + this.id);
  // or this if you have the '#'
  // var ids = $(this.id);
  if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
    $(ids[1]).remove();
  }
});
```

One of the comments mentions

> You script implies that there are multiple ids on the page: not good.

This is true if you are using the same id, which I do not think you are.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your `HTML` is an element with one of the classes `.cab_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas_user`, that either has no `id` attribute or has an empty one.

Change the line

```
var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
```

to

```
var ids = $('#' + this.id);
```

and the error will go away.

Or do a check for an empty `id`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".cab_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas, .cuerpo_librovisitas_user").each(function () {
        if (!this.id) return;
        var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
        if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
            $(ids[1]).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

...I can't help but wonder what the purpose of the code snippet is though... trying to remove duplicated elements...? Why are they there in the first place?